# How to use padding & margins properly in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to apply 100px of top margin to a *nested* row in Boostrap so that the content lines up vertically with some other content in the page - ok all good when you view on a large screen. When I shrink the browser size to mimic a tablet / phone the content shrinks and collapses down - also good. However, the 100px of margin causes the content to now be placed well down the tablet page - ugly.

I have thought about using media queries to eliminate the content with the 100px of margin for tablets & phones - but eliminating content seems like the wrong approach.

Many thanks for all your suggestions !

Comment: You should accept some of your previous questions

Comment: why not just use media queries to remove the 100px margin, in stead removing the content all together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content is unimportant for tablets and phones, then eliminating it is completely valid. Unfortunately, "unimportant" is EXTREMELY context dependent. However, you can just use media queries to set different styles (i.e. set 100px in full layout, set smaller or no margin in the tablet and mobile views)